# Jquery-te how to stop javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

An application that I support uses jquery-te: http://jqueryte.com/demos. When I insert into the html editor javascript code (like alert("Hello!")), it immediately executed. How can I disable its execution during editing html-text?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this without changing the source (at least I haven't found anything). If you're willing to change the source, try to look at where it insert the text area content into the display div, probably an change event. Then strip the script tags before that. You can ask if you have any doubt in the process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I resolved this problem. I changed the source code in my jquery-te-1.4.0.js file. Changes: 
line 263: 
from editor.attr("contenteditable","true").html(thisElementVal);
to editor.attr("contenteditable","true").val(thisElementVal);
line 999:
from    editor.html(extractToText(thisElement.val()));
to      editor.val(extractToText(thisElement.val()));

Comment: Please, if you can, answer your own question, and mark as accepted answer. This is more likely to help future visitors.

Comment: I hurried. This method solves the problem of executing javascript code, but I cannot see the content in preview.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by editing source code in my jquery-te-1.4.0.js file.
At first, I added 3 new variables:

```
    var scripts = [];
    var htmlWithoutScripts = "";
    var scriptPattern = /<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/g;
```

The second step was editing js-code on line 263:

```
editor.attr("contenteditable","true").html(thisElementVal);
```

was changed to

```
scripts = thisElementVal.match(scriptPattern);
htmlWithoutScripts = thisElementVal.replace(scriptPattern , "");
editor.attr("contenteditable","true").html(htmlWithoutScripts);
editor.attr("contenteditable","true").val(thisElementVal);
```

The third one was changing logic in function postToSource() (line 988). 
Added:

```
if(scripts !== null && scripts.length > 0)
{
      scripts.forEach(function(element){
      sourceStrings = sourceStrings.concat(element);
      });
}
```

before:

```
thisElement.val(extractToText(sourceStrings));
```

And the last one was changing logic in function postToEditor() (line 997).

Removed:

```
editor.html(extractToText(thisElement.val()));
```

Added:

```
var htmlContent = thisElement.val();
scripts = htmlContent.match(scriptPattern );
htmlWithoutScripts = htmlContent.replace(scriptPattern , "");
editor.html(extractToText(htmlWithoutScripts));
editor.val(extractToText(htmlContent));
```

If you have some remarks, please write in commets.

Comment: If it's not your library, you shouldn't edit its code. Extend it, or move to a new one

Comment: @blgt what's wrong in editing a open source project to fit your needs? Sure, it's best to do it is by cloning the repo, so you can push later changes. Or even submitting your changes to benefit future users.But changing the code is the point of OS licenses...

Comment: @Andre This has nothing to do with the licensing, merely with the fact that the next person who comes along to maintain it will be **completely unable** to do so. OTOH, when you e.g. clone the repo, you basically make the code your own, and maintainers will know that you forked and modded that specific version.